# Understanding deadlock in mysql 8.0.11

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-deadlocks

I found below deadlock in "Show engine innodb status" on myql 8.0.11. 
As per my understanding both queries should lock only one row (the primary key  user_id which is different for both queries). However the second query `"*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S): "RECORD LOCKS space id 5461 page no 76054 n bits 96 index PRIMARY of table`user"`

and First query is waiting to acquire same lock. I did not understand why? even when both lock statement say `"locks rec but not gap"` which means both are locking only individual records (which should have been their primary key user_id )
Would like to know is my understanding (as explained above) correct? If yes then how to explain the below logs?

```
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
update `user` set `user`.`xxxx` = 1 where ( user_id = 4939334)
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 5461 page no 76054 n bits 96 index PRIMARY of table `user` trx id 5385693398 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 24 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 20; compact format; info bits 0

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 2 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
update `user` set `user`.`xxxx` = 1 where ( user_id = 4917613)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 5461 page no 76054 n bits 96 index PRIMARY of table `user` trx id 5385693399 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 24 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 20; compact format; info bits 0


*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 5461 page no 63136 n bits 88 index PRIMARY of table `user` trx id 5385693399 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 19 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 20; compact format; info bits 0
```

Comment: They aren't trying to lock the same record.  1 is waiting for a lock that 2 already holds and now 2 seems to be trying to get a lock that conflicts with a lock that isn't mentioned elsewhere but may also be held by 1.  The deadlock seems to involve *other* queries each transaction has already run, when the deadlock is detected.  Can you identify what they were?

Comment: Hi Michael, I have clarified the questions more now, the point of contention is  "RECORD LOCKS space id 5461 page no 76054 n bits 96 index PRIMARY" only, which I want to understand as to why both query need same record lock as its a single row update with different primary key?

Comment: But transaction 2 is already waiting on _something_ in page 63136. We assume transaction 1 holds that lock from some earlier update made in the same transaction, even though that update isn't shown in the deadlock report. But once 2 is waiting to lock a row in page 63136, which 1 has locked, and 1 starts to wait to lock a row in page 76054, which 2 has locked, then it's a lock-wait cycle because both are waiting for something the other has locked.

Comment: Show us the SQL statements of both transactions.